# Python IndentationError - Codecademy: Python basics: Pyg Latin 9/12

Tags: python, indentation

Here's my code:

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
word = original.lower()
first = word[0]


if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
        if first in 'aeiou':
    print 'vowel'
            else:
                print "consonant"
        else:
            print "empty"
```

and here's the confusing error message:

> File "python", line 10
>       print 'vowel('
>                   ^) IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

It says this (") is the problem. I can't really continue my learning of Python without my step.

Comment: Does the Codeacademy course really not mention how important correct indentation is in Python? It should be literally the first or second thing you learn about Python.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: no, it does mention that, several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
word = original.lower()
first = word[0]

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    if first in 'aeiou':
        print 'vowel'
    else:
        print "consonant"
else:
    print "empty"
```

Indentation (the number of spaces from the left before each line of code) is important in Python. Each `if` and `else` must have the same indentation.

For instance...

```
if 1 == 1:

    else:
```

...will not work, because there's 0 spaces before `if` and there's 4 spaces before `else`. So each `else` that belongs to a `if` statement must be aligned.

Comment: btw not sure what `pyg` is for, but i left it there even tho you don't use it in this code..

Comment: Ye me neither it just asks me to do it. 
Thanks that's was really good explanation.
Ye i kinda wasn't aware about those spaces i was just looking at the "written(?)" code. I guess a noob mistake

Comment: @user3261814 Mistakes happen :) This is a good time to sell in an IDE or a more advance text-editor such as **Sublime Text 3* which will auto-indent for you :)

Answer (score 0):

you didn't apply indentation for printing vowel..
try this

```
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
if first in 'aeiou':
    print 'vowel'
else:
    print "consonant"
```